# Returning a single result field value as part of a record in a resulting data set from multiple tables using UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, union-all

I have a couple tables which I would like to compare data and return the last call date from CDR records.  The tables are described as follows :

**phonenumbers**

Contains a list of phone numbers with service.

**YYYY-MM**

Contains the CDR records for the period specified as the table name. YYYY = 4 digit year, MM = 2 digit month.

The query I have thus far is as follows :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
customerid,
phonenumber,
(SELECT Started FROM (
(SELECT * FROM `2016-08` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-07` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-06` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-05` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-04` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-03` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-02` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-01` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
) AS p ORDER BY p.Started DESC LIMIT 1) `lastcall`
FROM phonenumbers WHERE phonenumbers.dateterminated IS NULL AND
(
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '800%' OR
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '855%' OR
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '866%' OR
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '877%' OR
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '888%'
)
```

The above query logic is what I wish to achieve as a resulting list of all unique toll free numbers from my phonenumbers table, and the most recent `Started` (date  & time the call started) where the `Caller` number is the toll free number found in my phone numbers table exactly, OR the `Dialed` number is the toll free number found in my phone numbers table with a '1' prepended to it.

Unfortunately, running this query gives me the following error :

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS p ORDER BY p.Started DESC LIMIT 1) `lastcall`
>   FROM phonenumbers WHERE phon' at line 13

I have tried with and without naming the result set from the UNION ALL data (in the above example it is named `p` as `AS p`). The attempt I tried without naming it was as follows :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
customerid,
phonenumber,
(SELECT Started FROM (
(SELECT * FROM `2016-08` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-07` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-06` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-05` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-04` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-03` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-02` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `2016-01` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL
) ORDER BY Started DESC LIMIT 1) `lastcall`
FROM phonenumbers WHERE phonenumbers.dateterminated IS NULL AND
(
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '800%' OR
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '855%' OR
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '866%' OR
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '877%' OR
    phonenumbers.phonenumber LIKE '888%'
)
```

.. which results in this message :

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY Started DESC LIMIT 1) `lastcall`
>   FROM phonenumbers WHERE phonenumber' at line 13

*Same error, slightly different context which leads me to believe (as usual) the error is somewhere else, but the message is unclear and too generic to decipher what MySQL is complaining about*

How this query be adjusted to be functional given that all the fields and tables as specified in the query exist, and the context I have aptly described above ?

Comment: Remove "UNION ALL" from last union.
i.e. at 
(SELECT * FROM `2016-01` WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL

Comment: @CS_noob - totally missed that.  Thank you  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "UNION ALL" from last union. i.e. at `(SELECT * FROM 2016-01 WHERE Dialed = CONCAT('1', phonenumbers.phonenumber) OR Caller = phonenumbers.phonenumber) UNION ALL`.